# scala-play 2.4.11, is it possible to desearialize Map with case class as key?

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I'm trying to deal with play-json and it doesn't go well.
Here are my case classes

```
sealed case class Items(items: List[Item])

sealed case class Item(path: String, itemCounters: Map[ItemCategory, Long])

sealed case class ItemCategory(repository: Repository)

sealed case class Repository(env: String)
```

Here I'm trying to parse json:

```
implicit lazy val repositoryFormat = Json.format[Repository]
implicit lazy val itemCategoryFormat = Json.format[ItemCategory]
implicit lazy val itemFormat = Json.format[Item]
implicit lazy val itemsFormat = Json.format[Items]

Json.parse(str).as[Items]
```

I get exception:
**No implicit format for Map[ItemCategory,Long] available.**

Why?

Comment: Could you please post the JSON as well?

Comment: It fails at compile time :(

Comment: In isolation this code works, I think there is something missing/different in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because play-json is confused about how to deserialize `itemCounters: Map[ItemCategory, Long]` property in `Item`.

Indeed, JSON maps can be processed directly if the key is a `String`. But it becomes a bit tougher with other structured objects in keys, like `ItemCategory` in the question. Surely, the JSON with such key can't be `{ "repository": { "env": "demo" } }: 1`!

So, we need to be explicit about the deserialization of this sort of Map. I'm assuming that the key for an `ItemCategory` is the underlying `ItemCategory.repository.env` value, but it can be any other property depending on your effective data model.

We provide a `Reads` implementation for this kind of map:

```
implicit lazy val itemCategoryMapReads = new Reads[Map[ItemCategory, Long]] {
  override def reads(jsVal: JsValue): JsResult[Map[ItemCategory, Long]] = {
    JsSuccess(
      // the original string -> number map is translated into ItemCategory -> Long
      jsVal.as[Map[String, Long]].map{
        case (category, id) => (ItemCategory(Repository(category)), id)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

And the respective `Format` (with a stub for `Writes`, which we do not need right now):

```
implicit lazy val itemCategoryMapFormat = Format(itemCategoryMapReads, (catMap: Map[ItemCategory, Long]) => ???)
```

The base JSON is now mapped correctly:

```
val strItemCat =
  """
    | {
    |   "rep1": 1,
    |   "rep2": 2,
    |   "rep3": 3
    | }
  """.stripMargin

println(Json.parse(strItemCat).as[Map[ItemCategory, Long]])
// Map(ItemCategory(Repository(rep1)) -> 1, ItemCategory(Repository(rep2)) -> 2, ItemCategory(Repository(rep3)) -> 3)
```

For the other case classes, the straightforward formats that you already defined should work properly, provided that they are declared in order from most to least specific (from `Repository` to `Items`).

Comment: Thanks, it was bad decision to put object into map key. Thanks. I didn't think about it.